# How far in advance can I prepare Zabaglione before cooking sous-vide?

Tags: eggs, sous-vide, dessert

I an going to make a Zabaglione desert (egg yolks, sugar and Limoncello). This will be cooked sous-vide at 74C for 20 minutes and the pouch agitated occasionally during the cooking time.

Can I stick to this temperature and time combination if the raw Zabaglione is mixed and stored in a refrigerator beforehand?  Could I prepare this up to 24 hours in advance or is this one of these dishes that has to be prepared immediately before heating for best results?

Comment: What you’re describing sounds pretty stable, but it also doesn’t sound much like a zabaglione, which has air whisked into it during cooking.

Comment: It was indeed whisked before being added to the bag. In the end it was held for 3 hours before adding to the water bath. I was hoping that it would retain most of the aerated bulk but when it came to cooking the alcohol / sugar mixture had separated out. To remedy this I just agitated the contents before cooking. The final result was a delicious, very thick alcoholic custard. Next time though I will immediately add the the sous-vide bath after mixing to retain the bulk.

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing is essentially a simple eggnog without the milk, so as long as its in a sealed container, I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be perfectly fine for just 24 hours in the refrigerator. The only consideration would be if you put it in the sous vide while it is chilled, that might extend your cooking time by 5-10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sneftel commented above, following this process results in a different style of dessert than Zabaglione. I left the whipped mixture for approximately 3 hours before cooking, and by that time the sugar and alcohol mixture had separated. Too lazy to whisk it up again (and unsure if the liquid would indeed hold any air again after it had separated), I just agitated the bag before cooking. The result was a delicious alcoholic custard albeit with a thicker, denser consistency than the whipped version I remember.

Next time I will whip the mixture immediately prior to adding to the sous-vide bath. Due to the difference in cooking methods between sous-vide and Baine Marie, I suspect this version will be lighter than my "custard" but denser than the traditional method as it is not being whisked continuously during cooking.

So the answer is "No" if you want a Zabaglione the same texture as the traditional version. For me, the bigger question is can  you truly match the texture of eggs being whipped simultaneously over a Baine Marie with sous-vide? From what I can see watching various videos online, the protein sets towards the end of the cooking time, the continual whipping is to ensure air is constantly added to the mixture, something impossible with the sous-vide method.

I'd say the jury is still out if you can actually prepare a 100% genuine Zabaglione sous-vide, you can probably come close if you immediately add the beaten egg mixture, but food-chemistry suggests the results will be different.